# ANR Input timed out

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.)

Hi! I'm getting this strange ANR-report from several users. Unfortunately, I have very limited knowledge about ANR-reports, and I'm hoping that someone can help me to understand what the cause of this could be

```
"main" tid=1 Waiting 
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Waiting
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x733b6610 self=0x7b2cebea00
| sysTid=5982 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7bb1b3b9a8


| state=S schedstat=( 895549085 117045629 1679 ) utm=75 stm=13 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fc1071000-0x7fc1073000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
- waiting on <0x06cee88a> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ (Thread.java:2137)
- locked <0x06cee88a> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:358)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:190)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone (FutureTask.java:450)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get (FutureTask.java:192)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.get (AsyncTask.java:542)
  at trai.gov.in.dnd.app.DNDMasterActivityNEW.forceUpdateAppDialog (DNDMasterActivityNEW.java:281)
  at trai.gov.in.dnd.app.DNDMasterActivityNEW.Init (DNDMasterActivityNEW.java:272)
  at trai.gov.in.dnd.app.DNDMasterActivityNEW.onCreate (DNDMasterActivityNEW.java:92)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6999)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6990)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2731)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2856)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1589)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6494)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
"AsyncTask #1" tid=12 Native Performing network I/O
"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=12 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12dc0000 self=0x7b21fef800
  | sysTid=6009 nice=10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b176854f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 226769531 4555214 150 ) utm=20 stm=1 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7b17583000-0x7b17585000 stackSize=1037KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000006a58c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ppoll+8)
  #01  pc 00000000000264c0  /system/lib64/libc.so (poll+88)
  #02  pc 000000000002ea78  /system/lib64/libjavacore.so (???)
  #03  pc 0000000000236ad0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (Java_libcore_io_Linux_poll___3Landroid_system_StructPollfd_2I+160)
  at libcore.io.Linux.poll (Native method)
  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.poll (BlockGuardOs.java:216)
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected (IoBridge.java:254)
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno (IoBridge.java:188)
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect (IoBridge.java:130)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356)
- locked <0x0b28cfd7> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:357)
  at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:616)
  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket (PlainSocketFactory.java:124)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection (DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open (AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open (AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute (DefaultRequestDirector.java:366)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute (AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute (AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute (AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
  at trai.gov.in.dnd.extras.Network.HttpCallToServer (Network.java:122)
  at trai.gov.in.dnd.extras.AsyncNetworkWithID.doInBackground (AsyncNetworkWithID.java:32)
  at trai.gov.in.dnd.extras.AsyncNetworkWithID.doInBackground (AsyncNetworkWithID.java:10)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:333)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:245)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: You're probably doing a resource-intensive task somewhere in your app. I don't know how your code looks but I'd advise you use threads to manipulate time spent on doing certain task.

Comment: should i use thread in whole app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ANR happens when a long operation is taking place in the main (primary) thread. If this thread is busy, Android cannot process any further GUI events in the application, and thus throws up an ANR dialog.

Obviously, you have a part of your code that's using up a lot of resources or taking time to complete.. That's what is making your app throw an ANR.

Check your `DNDMasterActivityNEW.java` class, there is something delaying the dispatching of your input. There are a couple of ways to solve this:

- You can use a `progressbar` to indicate when the dispatching is going on and set the visibility to "GONE" when it's done.
- Use a different thread for the dispatching.
- Find a more time-friendly alternative to the current method you're using to dispatch your input.

Post your `DNDMasterActivityNEW.java` code if you still can't solve the problem.